# MS Word: How to insert logo between page border?

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to insert a logo in between the top of a page border, similar to the sample below. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

1. Add the picture to a page with border (Design > Page Background > Border).
2. Change the paragraph justification of that paragraph to centered.

Comment: that didn't work,
can you please create a sample word doc so I can use as a template

Comment: Sorry, there's no attach function on SuperUser.